# Parse API Json response in JMeter and create a payload by modifying few values based on certain criteria

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

I am trying to parse the whole response from API 1 in JMeter and make few changes in the payload and pass it to next API.

For an Instance, I am fetching below response from API 1:

> {
> "environments": [
> {
> "id": "123",
> "databases": [
> {
> "environmentType": "abc",
> "dbName": "DB1",
> "dbSize": 10,
> "provisionType": "serverless",
> "vCores": 2
> },
> {
> "environmentType": "abc",
> "dbName": "DB2",
> "dbSize": 10,
> "provisionType": "serverless",
> "vCores": 2
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> }

Now I need to modify the provision type as "provisioned" and vCores as 4 only if dbName is "DB2" and rest all payload should remain same. This modified json payload has to be passed as an input in API 2.

I tried parsing in JSR223 postprocessor using below libraries but facing issues while preparing the required request for API 2.

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
```

Need some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

json.environments.each { environment ->
    environment.databases.each { database ->
        if (database.dbName == "DB2") {
            database.vCores = 4
            database.provisionType = "provisioned"
        }
    }
}

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString())
```

the generated payload can be accessed as `${payload}` where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: is there any method to remove few attributes from the payload? let say I want to delete dbSize attribute altogether for DB2 in above snippet.